# fragment transaction - pop backstack and then add fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to do the following use case in Android Fragments. I have 2 fragments.
Fragment A -> Fragment B
When a user does something in Fragment B, I want to have the back stack as follows
Fragment A -> Fragment C. So, when the user presses back I want the user to go back to Fragment A.

I have tried the following

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fMgr.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.base, Fragment_C, "1")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The problem here is that I can see Fragment A for a short period of time before Fragment C is shown

If I do the following

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fMgr.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.base, Fragment_C, "1")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

I get the error

> This transaction is already being added to the back stack

I can get Fragment C to show up if I do this BUT

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fMgr.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.base, Fragment_C, "1")
            .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

This works and I don't see Fragment A and see Fragment C but the back button takes the user out of the application. So, is it possible that we can pop the back stack of the fragment and then add another fragment to the back stack w/o showing Fragment A **AND** the back button takes the user back to Fragment A

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy method to add fragments to fragments or to adapters within fragments...

1. from your base activity, make your fragment manager static. assume this activity is called dashboard.

   ```
   static FragmentManager support;
   ```
2. Don't forget to initialize this in onCreate.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.layout_dashboard);
   support = getSupportFragmentManager();
   ```
3. define your new fragment inside your adapter or fragment.

   ```
   users_item_fragment dialog = new users_item_fragment();
   //also, let's add some data...
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("device", devicesList.get(position));
   ```
4. use the following method to add the fragment easily wherever you would like

   ```
   //pick an easily remembered tag
   public void replace(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    FragmentManager man = dashboard.support;
    FragmentTransaction fragt = man.beginTransaction();

    if(!fragment.isAdded()) {
       dashboard.lastTag = dashboard.fragtag;//not needed, but helpful w/ backpresses
       fragt.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
               .hide(man.findFragmentByTag(fragtag)).commit();
       dashboard.fragtag = dashboard.tag;//not needed, but helpful w/ backpresses
    }
    if(fragment.isAdded() && fragment.isHidden()) {
       dashboard.lastTag = dashboard.fragtag;//not needed, but helpful w/ backpresses
       fragt.show(fragment);
       fragt.hide(man.findFragmentByTag(fragtag)).commit();
       dashboard.fragtag = dashboard.tag;//not needed, but helpful w/ backpresses
    }
   }
   ```
5. To implement this with backpresses working correctly, add this in you onBackPress method of your main activity:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       FragmentManager man = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = man.beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragtag))
       .show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(lastTag)).commit();
       fragtag = lastTag;// holds the last fragment

   }
   }
   ```

It's easy to see the logic here and easy to manipulate back press events using this.